# how to convert numbers so that it can plot range on graph

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, calculation, algebra

our graph is from 0-64. However, our data is 0-100. How can i convert our data so that it would plot on our graph? It does not have to be absolutely accurate, ball park is ok.

Answer (score 0):

to match the graph you may calculate the value
on graph = value * 0.64